# list duplicate files on linux and concatenate they keeping the header of the first one

Tags: linux, list, concatenation

I have one peculiar issue to fix, I need list duplicate files on linux and concatenate they keeping the header of the first one.

A got this Error bellow.

awk: fatal: cannot open file `CnB_PO_*_ASAM_ASAM_*.csv' for reading (No such file or directory)

the code it i used is,

ls -l ./CnB_PO_*_ASAM_*_*.csv | for i in `ls -1 ./ CnB_PO_*_ASAM_*_*.csv | cut -d'_' -f5 | uniq`; do awk '!a[$0]++' ./ CnB_PO_*_ASAM_"$i"_*.csv > ./ CnB_PO_ASAM_"$i"_END.csv; done

the question is: this file does not  exist "CnB_PO_*_ASAM_ASAM_*.csv"

the AWK created and i dont see where.

any idea?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: what i have until now is this : "awk 'ls -ltr !a[$0]++' teste*" and my issue is how to list anly the file duplicated.